# Error while connecting to the MariadDB maxscale with tx

Tags: mariadb, centos7, columnstore, maxscale

While I tried connecting my Mariadb TX server using `mxs_adapter` and `cdc` connectors I get the following error:

```
2018-09-20 16:12:38 [cdc_test.cdc_tab] MaxScale connection could not be 
created: Exception caught: basic_string::_S_create
2018-09-20 16:12:38 [cdc_test.cdc_tab] Received fatal signal 11
mxs_adapter[0x42bfd5]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf6d0)[0x7f4081ba96d0]
mxs_adapter(mysql_close+0x12)[0x434b02]
mxs_adapter(_Z11streamTableSsSs+0x26a)[0x41d89a]
mxs_adapter(_ZNSt6thread5_ImplISt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvSsSsESsSsEEE6
_M_runEv+0x37)[0x41eeb7]
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb5070)[0x7f4080e5b070]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25)[0x7f4081ba1e25]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f40805bfbad]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've hit a bug. The best way to solve it is to report it on the [MariaDB Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL). Add the output you added here and explain what you were trying to do. It's more than likely that it will get fixed in the next release.

Meanwhile, you can try the cdc.py client that is packaged with MaxScale to verify that your MaxScale CDC setup is working.